# How to calculate the amazon signature for HTTP call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, signature

I want to integrate the new service from Amazon Elastic Transcoder. Since my application is running on python 2.4 can't use boto.

So I am writing direct http call. The problem I have is that it tells me this when I do post requests, but works for get request:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import urlparse
import requests
import json

proxy = { 
              "http"  : "http://10.254.252.100:3128", 
              "https" : "http://10.254.252.100:3128", 
            }



class AWSSignerV4(object):
    '''
    AWS V4 signature class.
    '''

    def __init__(self, access_key, key, http_verb, uri, headers, payload='', service=None, region=None):
        '''
        Instantiates a AWS V4 request signer (HMAC-256).

        :param access_key: AWS access key.
        :param key: AWS access secret key.
        :param http_verb: Request HTTP verb (e.g., GET or POST)
        :param uri: Request URL (http://<aws-service>.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/[something]
        :param headers: dict with the headers used on the request. This dictionary will be updated with the authentication headers.
        :param payload: Optional payload for PUT or POST requests.
        :param service: Optional service name. By default it will be derived from the uri parameter.
        :param region: Optional AWS datacentre region. By default it will be derived from the uri parameter.
        '''
        self._key = key
        self._headers = headers
        self._http_verb = http_verb
        self._access_key = access_key
        self._payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(payload).hexdigest().lower()

        parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(uri)
        expanded_netloc = parsed_url.netloc.split('.')

        if service is None:
            service = expanded_netloc[0]

        if region is None:
            region = expanded_netloc[1]

        self._service = service
        self._region = region

        if 'x-amz-date' not in headers:
            headers['x-amz-date'] = self.generate_request_date()

        self._timestamp = headers['x-amz-date']
        headers['x-amz-credential'] = self.credential_scope

        self._path = parsed_url.path
        self._query_string = self._canonicalise_querystring(parsed_url.query.strip())
        self._cheaders, self._signed_headers = self._canonicalise_headers(self._headers, parsed_url.netloc)
        self._headers['Authorization'] = self.authorization_header

    def __call__(self):
        '''
        This method (that makes an instance of this class a callable object) will return the updated header dictionary, including
        the AWS authorization headers.
        '''
        return self._headers

    #############################################
    # Instance properties
    @property
    def authorization_header(self):
        return 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={}/{}, SignedHeaders={}, Signature={}'.format(self._access_key, self.credential_scope,
                                                                                          self._signed_headers, self.request_signature)

    @property
    def request_signature(self):
        return hmac.new(self.signature_key, self.string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    @property
    def canonical_request_hash(self):
        request = '{self._http_verb}\n{self._path}\n{self._query_string}\n{self._cheaders}\n{self._signed_headers}\n{self._payload_hash}'.format(**locals())
        return hashlib.sha256(request).hexdigest().lower()

    @property
    def string_to_sign(self):
        return 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(self._timestamp, self.credential_scope, self.canonical_request_hash)

    @property
    def credential_scope(self):
        request_date = self._timestamp[:8]
        return '{}/{}/{}/aws4_request'.format(request_date, self._region, self._service)

    @property
    def signature_key(self):
        sign = lambda k, m: hmac.new(k, m.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

        k_date = sign(('AWS4' + self._key).encode('utf-8'), self._timestamp[:8])
        k_region = sign(k_date, self._region)
        k_service = sign(k_region, self._service)
        return sign(k_service, 'aws4_request')

    #########################################
    # Class methods
    @staticmethod
    def generate_request_date():
        return time.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ', time.gmtime())

    @staticmethod
    def _canonicalise_querystring(query):
        assert(query == '')  # TODO proper query string support will be added if required!
        return ''

    @staticmethod
    def _canonicalise_headers(headers, host):
        canonical_headers = {}
        canonical_headers_str = ''

        for key, value in headers.iteritems():
            canonical_headers[key.lower()] = value.strip()  # change to regexp to remove spaces not within "

        if 'host' not in canonical_headers:
            canonical_headers['host'] = host

        for key, value in sorted(canonical_headers.iteritems()):
            canonical_headers_str += '{}:{}\n'.format(key, value)

        return (canonical_headers_str, ';'.join(sorted(canonical_headers.keys())))


# Sample code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    headers = {}

#    uri = 'https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/pipelines/1360339173389-562f0b'
    uri = 'https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/pipelines/'
#    uri = 'https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs/1360339319640-ef1c5b'
#    uri = 'https://elastictranscoder.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2012-09-25/jobs/'
    test_obj = AWSSignerV4('acess key', 'private key', 'POST', uri, headers)

    headers = test_obj()
    payload = {'Name': 'Testweb',
               'InputBucket':'testjd5',
               'OutputBucket':'testfinals',
               'Role':'arn:aws:iam::789823056103:role/Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role',
               'Notifications':{'Progressing': '', 'Completed': '', 'Warning': '', 'Error': ''}
               }
#    payload = {'Input': {"Key":"9761.webm",
#                  "FrameRate":"auto",
#                  "Resolution":"auto",
#                  "AspectRatio":"auto",
#                  "Interlaced":"auto",
#                  "Container":"webm"},
#               'Output':{"Key":"test.mp4",
#                  "ThumbnailPattern":"",
#                  "Rotate":"0",
#                  "PresetId":"1351620000000-100020"},
#               'PipelineId':'1360339173389-562f0b'
#               }
#    headers['Content-Length']= '%s'%(value)
#    print uri
#    for key, value in headers.iteritems():
#            call_header['%s'%(key)]= '%s'%(value)

#    print headers
    print requests.post(uri, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload), proxies=proxy).text
#    print requests.get(uri, headers=headers,  proxies=proxy).text
```

Can you please have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was quite frustrated with AWS sqs api and request signing in python 3 I decided to create a project on github. I have just pushed the project so it is in a very early stage but I will soon add more functionality. Good news is it already has what you need: AWS version 4 signing algorithm: https://github.com/rcosnita/aws-tests

Take a look at:
- https://github.com/rcosnita/aws-tests/blob/master/aws/sqs/tests/itest_sqs_client.py

This should get you started with aws request signing.

Good luck and please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have found what I was doing wrong, for post I didn't send the additional payload that was required. As a side note it's funny that you replay. We went to the same university. I remember your name from all exams.